# How to connect to ssh server using c#?

Tags: c#

How to connect to ssh server using c#?For exaple to read files located home\files\test.txt.I wanted to find guides,but there isn't any about this.

Comment: This was asked before (kindda), maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169396/c-sharp-send-a-simple-ssh-command

Comment: You need 3rd party library for that : https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

Comment: This question may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516284/in-c-sharp-how-to-run-unix-command-on-remote-ssh-using-tcpclient